# integer extraction from list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contain lists:
mylist=[[2],[9],[3],[5],[7]]

Is there a way in python to get the value of the inner list (not just print it)?
Therefore, we would get integer 2 from the list mylist[0]. Without iterating the whole mylist.

Comment: You mean: `mylist[0][0]`

Comment: The first element of the list `[2]` is `2` and `[2]` is the first element of `mylist`

Comment: yeah but the list [2] is in mylist. I can't use integer 2 in addition for example.

Comment: What do you mean? If you do `print mylist[0][0] + 5`, you get `7`

Comment: Nothing, I am an idiot. This is correct. I didn't try to do that, because in C and C++ I use list[0][0] for a 2 dimensional array. I didn't think of mylist as having 2 dimensions.

Comment: Well, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a specific value, use `mylist[instance][0]`.

This would work, because it gets the i<sup>th</sup> value, but then gets the 0<sup>th</sup> value of that because it is still a list:

```
>>> mylist=[[2],[9],[3],[5],[7]]
>>> mylist[0]
[2]
>>> mylist[0][0]
2
>>>
```

Alternatively, you could *flatten* it and then access it normally:

```
>>> mylist=[[2],[9],[3],[5],[7]]
>>> mylist = [item for sub in mylist for item in sub]
>>> mylist
[2, 9, 3, 5, 7]
>>> mylist[0]
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of lists is similar to having a 2-D array. To reference an element of the inner list, just use

> `mylist[i][j]`

where `i` refers to the index of the list and `j` to the element in that list.
In the case of 2, this would be:

> `mylist[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Think of your list like this:

```
mylist=
[[2],
[9],
[3],
[5],
[7]]
```

`mylist[0] = [2]` which is an array, to access the number in the array mylist as explained is `mylist[0][0]` which = the int 2

eg

```
mylist[1][0] = 2
```

If mylist was

```
mylist=    
[[2, 3],
[9, 10],
[3, 4],
[5, 6],
[7, 8]]
```

`mylist[0][1] = 3` and `mylist[1][1] = 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist=[[2],[9],[3],[5],[7]]    
newList=[]
for each in str(mylist).replace('[','').replace(']','').strip().split(','):
    newList.append(int(each))
print newList
```

or

```
newList = eval('[' + str(mylist).replace('[','').replace(']','').strip() +']')
```